# Google Maps height issue with CSS Flexbox model

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, flexbox

I have a simple layout where the body takes the full height minus height of the footer + height of the header. This is achieved with flexbox model (http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; /* to avoid scrollbars */
        }
        #wrapper {
            display: flex; /* use the flex model */
            min-height: 100%;
            flex-direction: column; /* learn more: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ */
        }
        #header {
            background: yellow;
            height: 100px; /* can be variable as well */
        }
        #body {
            flex: 1;
            border: 1px solid orange;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #footer {
            background: lime;
        }
        #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">Title</div>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer<br />
            of<br />
            variable<br />
            height<br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am facing a problem with google maps. I cannot initialise it into the canvas div because (I assume that's the reason) it does not have a defined height.

Is there any way to make google maps appear?

Thanks

Comment: How are you including the flexbox?

Comment: @geocodezip, It is supported by all modern browsers nowadays without any 3rd party JS

Answer (score 11):

`height: 100%` is not working as expected. You can use absolute positioning to size the Google map:

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
#body {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}
#footer {
  background: lime;
}
#map-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Title</div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer<br/>of<br/>variable<br/>height
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the `#map-canvas` height to the height of the `#body` element in JavaScript before creating your map.

```
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
mapCanvas.style.height = document.getElementById('body').clientHeight + 'px';
```

jQuery version:

```
$('#map-canvas').height($('#body').height());
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/xgz06v29/)</kbd>